# TypeAccessException: Attempt by method ... to access type ... failed

Tags: .net

The full exception details are:

```
System.TypeAccessException occurred
  Message=Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.(System.Text.StringBuilder, System.Object, Int32)' to access type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.Object,NetworkCatcher.Entities.Server.CalculatedFCStateManager+Descriptor>>' failed.
  Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
  TypeName=""
  StackTrace:
       at (StringBuilder , Object , Int32 )
  InnerException:
```

The method name `DynamicClass.(System.Text.StringBuilder, System.Object, Int32)` corresponds to this dynamically generated method:

```
private delegate StringBuilder AppendToStringBuilderDelegate(StringBuilder sb, object obj, int maxItemsToDisplay);

private static AppendToStringBuilderDelegate EmitDelegate(Type type, MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
  var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, typeof(StringBuilder), TypeArray<StringBuilder, object, int>.Value);
  var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();

  var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, parameters[1].ParameterType);
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
  il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo, null);
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
  return s_methodCache[type] = (AppendToStringBuilderDelegate)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(AppendToStringBuilderDelegate));
}
```

The stack trace is:

```
[Lightweight Function]  
Shunra.Common.dll!Shunra.Common.DebugUtils.AppendObject<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object,NetworkCatcher.Entities.Server.CalculatedFCStateManager.Descriptor>>(System.Text.StringBuilder sb, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object,NetworkCatcher.Entities.Server.CalculatedFCStateManager.Descriptor> obj, int maxItemsToDisplay) Line 261 + 0x14 bytes    C#
Shunra.Common.dll!Shunra.Common.DebugUtils.ToString<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object,NetworkCatcher.Entities.Server.CalculatedFCStateManager.Descriptor>>(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object,NetworkCatcher.Entities.Server.CalculatedFCStateManager.Descriptor> obj, int maxItemsToDisplay) Line 435 + 0x4d bytes  C#
NC.Entities.Server.dll!NetworkCatcher.Entities.Server.CalculatedFCStateManager.Populate() Line 98 + 0x2c bytes  C#
NC.Entities.Server.dll!NetworkCatcher.Entities.Server.RunManager.Initialize() Line 500 + 0x1c bytes C#
NC.Entities.Server.dll!NetworkCatcher.Entities.Server.EntryPoint.OnStart() Line 63 + 0x5 bytes  C#
Shunra.Infra.dll!Shunra.Infra.EntryPoint.Start() Line 37 + 0xb bytes    C#
Shunra.Common.dll!Shunra.Common.Wcf.ShunraServiceHost.OnOpening() Line 47 + 0x11 bytes  C#
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(System.TimeSpan timeout) + 0x113 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open() + 0x25 bytes    
NC.Server.Host.exe!NetworkCatcher.Server.Host.NCServerInstance.StartHosts() + 0xef bytes    
Shunra.Common.dll!Shunra.Common.Wcf.ShunraServerInstance<NetworkCatcher.Server.Host.NCServerInstance,NetworkCatcher.Server.Host.ServerHost>.Run() Line 357 + 0xb bytes  C#
NC.Server.Host.exe!NetworkCatcher.Server.Host.Program.Main(string[] args) + 0x84 bytes
```

Finally, the two assemblies - Shunra.Common.dll and NC.Entities.Server.dll belong to the same codebase. NC.Entities.Server.dll is loaded from the private bin folder located immediately below the root folder, where Shunra.Common.dll lives.

Everything worked just fine, until I decided to run the code under another account. So, I created a new account, made it an admin and opened an elevated console window under this account.
The account has access to all the files. Still, when I run the application I get this error and I am completely lost at it.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue recently and it turned out that the type I called (i.e. `MethodInfo.DeclaringType`) was internal. After setting it to public, the type access succeeded.

Comment: This visibility problem can be also fixed if you use the parameter 'restrictedSkipVisibility: true' while instantiating the DynamicMethod. Trust levels between the invoking assembly and the type you're accessing should be compatible, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You might find out more about what happened by running fuslogvw (the Fusion Log Viewer). If you aren't familiar with this, it enables you to log all binds and attempted binds to .NET assemblies - it will tell you all the paths probed to find an assembly, and might provide you more reasons for a bind failure. If you are familiar with it, you can ignore the rest of what I've got to say!

If it isn't a bind failure, at least you've eliminated one possibility.

To run the viewer, fuslogvw from a Visual Studio cmmand prompt, and change the settings from Log disabled to either Log bind failures to disk or Log all binds to disk (according to preference). Run your code again and click refresh. Double click on an entry to see the detail.

Make sure you disable the log when you finish - fuslogvw is monitoring binds across *all* processes and if you leave it running your computer will 1) be slow, 2) fill up with logs.

Comment: OK, I ran fuslogvw both with log binding failures and with log all. Did not see anything extraordinary, but if you have anything concrete in mind - please tell me what to post and I will.

Comment: Nothing more concrete than looking to see if any of the binds for your application failed - but you'd have to double-click on the entries in the main window to see the details for each bind. Otherwise I'm fairly stumped too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar exception, and symptom of the exception revolving around a delegate type and using CallBase = true on my Moq'ed class.

What resolved this for me was making the delegate public in scope so it was visible through Moq. We had originally scoped the delegate as protected and I was receiving this exception, so it seems public scope is required.

In the case of the original question, I think you'd need to change

```
private delegate StringBuilder AppendToStringBuilderDelegate(StringBuilder sb, object obj, int maxItemsToDisplay);
```

to

```
public delegate StringBuilder AppendToStringBuilderDelegate(StringBuilder sb, object obj, int maxItemsToDisplay);
```