# How to access a private constructor from controller to model class in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, deserialization

Is there any way to access a private constructor from controller to model?
The controller containing method calling the model is as follows:

```
public ActionResult ReadXML()
{
    XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Asseted>));
    TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Tial2.xml");
    List<Asseted> asseted;
    List<Asseted> list = new List<Asseted>();
    asseted = (List<Asseted>)reader.Deserialize(textReader);
    textReader.Close();
    for (int i = 0; i < asseted.Count; i++)
    {
        string data123 =  Convert.ToString(asseted[i].PopertyValue);
        string data234 = Convert.ToString(asseted[i].PropertyName);
        list.Add(new Asseted(data123,data234));

    }
    return View();
}
```

The model containing the Method to be called is as follows:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Asseted
{
    string pName, pValue;
    private string data234;
    private string data123;

    private Asseted(string data234, string data123)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        PropertyName = data234;
        PopertyValue = data123;
    }
    [XmlElement]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string PopertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why you need a private constructor in your Asseted class?

Comment: Because i want to print the name/value pair from controller to view as a List as string

Comment: Short answer is no (private means private to the class itself). But what is the point of your loop. Your `asseted = (List<Asseted>)reader.Deserialize(textReader);` code already creates the collection. What is the point of creating another identical collection? And why are you using `string data123 =  Convert.ToString(asseted[i].PopertyValue);` to convert a `string` to another `string` (its already `string`)

Comment: it is still not working

Comment: what exacly is your problem? Did you try/evaluate the hints of @Kundan and @Stephen?

Comment: Yes now i got the answer finally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to access a private constructor from controller to model?

While it may be arguable if this is the *right* way to solve your problem, the question itself can be answered with **YES**. And it's not even very hard with reflection.

```
ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(Asseted).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, 
    null, 
    new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }, 
    null);

Asseted instance = constructor.Invoke(new[] { 
    "data234", 
    "data123" 
}) as Asseted;
```

Basically you get the type (`Asseted`), get the constructor that matches your known parameter types and invoke it. Done.

Additional Note:
Depending on your compiler and actual code, you might run into a [`TypeAccessException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356371/help-needed-with-typeaccessexception-attempt-by-method-to-access-type-f).